# Make IE9 render as IE7 without editing the site code

Tags: internet-explorer-9, rendering

On my computer at work, I am one of the few running Windows 7. Because of this, I have IE9, and the LPS site does not work unless I render the page as IE7.

Searching for a way to make IE render it without changing the settings every time the page changes leads me to results for the code that a web developer should be using, but I can't do that.

How can I force IE9 to render as IE7 on it's own? (Ideally by site, but overall is fine too.)

Answer (score 0):

- ```
  Fire up Internet Explorer.
  ```
- Click the 'Tools' menu, then click 'Developer Tools'. Alternatively, just press F12.

That should open the Developer Tools window. That window has two menu items that are of interest:

- Browser Mode. This setting determines the value of the user-agent header sent for every request.
- Document Mode. This setting determines how the rendering engine renders the page.

More at [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20151127050454/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2010/06/16/ie-s-compatibility-features-for-site-developers.aspx)

Comment: I do this all the time. But since the site has some popups that could potentially expire because it has to load the page again after changing the setting, I'm looking for a way to have this happen automatically.